# Pipenv with Conda?

Tags: python, anaconda, git-bash, pipenv

I'm using Anaconda for my virtualenvs in win 10. I'm using git-bash .I've been reading about pipenv recently and decided to give it a try. I installed pipenv on my base conda python which is a version of python 2.7 using :

```
pip install pipenv
```

I can easily create a python environment using

```
conda create --name py3 python=3.6
```

but I tried:

```
$ pipenv install --three
```

which gave:

```
Warning: Python 3 was not found on your system…
You can specify specific versions of Python with:
  $ pipenv --python path\to\python
....\miniconda2\lib\site-packages\pipenv\_compat.py:86: ResourceWarning: Implicitly cleaning up <TemporaryDirectory 'c:\\users\\......\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pipenv-4_fzvq-requi
rements'>
  warnings.warn(warn_message, ResourceWarning)
```

Is it possible to use the 2 packages together?

Comment: You need to have `python3` on your path or explicitly state it.

Comment: Ok , I read that too, but my anaconda has a python27 in the base path not python3. Is there a way to add python3 there?

Answer (score 40):

You can setup Pipenv to use Conda's Python executable and site packages directory ([ref](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/#pipenv-and-other-python-distributions)).

```sh
pipenv --python=$(conda run which python) --site-packages
```

You can check if you are indeed using your Conda environment in Pipenv:

```
pipenv run python
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable, sys.path
# <directories under your Conda environment>
```

With NumPy installed through Conda, but not Pipenv, you can see that Pipenv will still find NumPy.

```
conda install numpy
pipenv run python
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.__file__
# <path under your Conda environment>
```

When you install NumPy through Pipenv, it will shadow Conda's installation of the the package.

```
pipenv install numpy
pipenv run python
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.__file__
# <path under your Pipenv environment>
```

Comment: How to undo `pipenv --python=$(conda run which python) --site-packages`? @anishpatel

Answer (score 19):

You can install pipenv within a conda environment initialized with python 3.

```
$ conda create -n pipenv-test python=3
$ source activate pipenv-test
(pipenv-test)$ pipenv install --python=/home/.../miniconda3/envs/pipenv-test/bin/python
Creating a virtualenv for this project…
Using /home/.../miniconda3/envs/pipenv-test/bin/python (3.6.5) to create virtualenv…
⠋Already using interpreter /home/.../miniconda3/envs/pipenv-test/bin/python
Using base prefix '/home/.../miniconda3/envs/pipenv-test'
New python executable in /home/.../.local/share/virtualenvs/wispy-j1ojliDY/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.

Virtualenv location: /home/.../.local/share/virtualenvs/wispy-j1ojliDY
Creating a Pipfile for this project…
Pipfile.lock not found, creating…
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
Locking [packages] dependencies…
Updated Pipfile.lock (ca72e7)!
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (ca72e7)…
     ▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉ 0/0 — 00:00:00
To activate this project's virtualenv, run the following:
 $ pipenv shell
```

This seems to work for me but I haven't tested it extensively. Also, my base conda python is 3.6 and I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. I'm curious to hear whether this still gives you trouble.

Comment: I'm trying your commands in git-bash . in the pipenv-test conda env  do you need to run pip install pipenv before '$ pipenv install ..miniconda\envs\pipenv-test ?
'

Comment: I did 'conda install pip' but it turns out it was installed by default. You can check if it's there with 'conda list'. But that may be a difference between linux and the window anaconda git bash.

Comment: It may be that git-bash is not supported yet based on https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/970

Comment: How do your steps show how "you can install pipenv within a conda environment initialized with Python 3"? That seems to imply running something like `pip install pipenv` within the environment, but your instructions assume pipenv is already available after activation.

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply. @rob3c you are correct, I forgot to include that in my original answer. I did in fact do `pip install pipenv` within the conda environment first.

Comment: Its not a good thing to use pip with conda. https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/

Comment: This is excellent advice. Always create a separate conda environment if experimenting with lots of packages. However, note that this blog was written when conda 4.6.0 was in beta, and they're currently on version 4.7.5. I have noticed the issue getting better, but always err on the side of caution!

Answer (score -3):

without the '$'

```
pipenv install --three
```

Comment: I believe the `$` is meant as the terminal entry, not part of the command...