# Pipenv shell doesn't reconize Python command

Tags: python, pipenv

I'm getting started with Python, and I have already installed Python (I'm using miniconda) and Pipenv. I know both are correctly installed because if I run somehting like `python version` or `pipenv version`, I get a correct output, but after I access `pipenv shell` and try running `python` to access the python interpreter, it just remains blank. I don't even get an error message. It is as if it crashes. Just to add more information, I had the same happen before if I ran `python` in the terminal, and I saw that I needed to use the `winpty python` command, but I created an alias to rename it as `python`, and although it works outside of the pipenv shell, it doesn't run in this one.

Comment: For what reason do you want to combine conda environments with pipenv environments? This is asking for trouble!

Comment: @Peter Why? Elaborate.

Comment: It's actually your task to explain why you are doing this, what you want to achive with it and what you already tried to solve your issue.

Comment: @Peter I wasn't doing anything specific. I'm learning Python using codecademy and I initially installed python using miniconda as they recommended. Then today I learned about pipenv and I installed it and I got into trouble when I tried running the Python interpreter in it. I also solved it using the `winpty` command, but I guess it's because it can't access the alias I for it outside of the pipenv terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conda and pipenv are the leading Python package managers that allow you to create virtual environements and install 3rd party packages into them. A virtual environement is a Python installation with defined package-versions that are supposed to work together to support your programming needs. Your Python code plus your environment definition will allow others to run your program on their machines, even if they have a different operation system.

[Conda environments](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html): How to create a conda environment

```
> conda create --name myenv pandas matplotlib
> conda activate myenv
(myenv) > conda list --explicit > myenv.txt
(myenv) > python
```

Recreate this environment via:

```
conda env create --file myenv.txt
```

[Pipenv environemnts](https://pipenv-fork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics.html): How to create a pipvenv environment

```
> pipenv install pandas matplotlib
> pipenv shell
(.venv) > python
```

`pipenv install` automatically creates 'Pipfile' in your project folder that will be used to recreate this environemnt via:

```
> pipenv install
```

With your project you can activate **one environment only, not both**. You can install pipenv based on Anaconda [Pipenv with Conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50546339/pipenv-with-conda), but this has no advantage at all.

However, the big advantage of Anaconda is that they suppose to guaranty maximum consitency for the 'scientific stack' (numpy, pandas, scipy, matplotlib), but you might experience that not all pypi packages are available on anaconda.org, so that you have to `pip install` (NOT `pipenv install`) packages into a conda environment, which is acceptable, as long as it is not the base environment.

Comment: Okay got it. I knew pipenv was a python environment, but I didn't know that both conda and pipenv are, esentially, just different ways to do the same. So, does that mean that I can't (or at least, it's "not recommended") have two different environments of Python at the same time? (meaning conda and pipenv), just in case I wanted to use them for different things. Or is this just looking for trouble? Thanks for the clarification.