# Failed to create a virtual environment using pipenv inside a conda Python 3.8.3 environment on Windows

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv, pipenv

System and environment details: 
Anaconda based python environment on a Windows 10 PC 
conda 4.8.5 
Python 3.8.3 
pipenv version 2020.8.13

I wish to launch a virtual environment for a new project, install the dependencies inside that virtual environment and run the code. The project is located in the code/ directory on my PC. I installed pipenv in my PC for creating a virtual environment using `pip install pipenv`. To create a virtual environment using pipenv, I executed the command `pipenv shell` from the root of my project directory (code) and got the following output.

```
$ pipenv shell
Creating a virtualenv for this project...
Pipfile: C:\Users\myPC\code\Pipfile
Using C:/Users/myPC/Anaconda3/python.exe (3.8.3) to create virtualenv...
[==  ] Creating virtual environment...FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\users\\myPC\\anaconda3\\Lib\\venv\\scripts\\nt\\python.exe'

Failed creating virtual environment

[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:
Failed to create virtual environment.
```

The python executable being pointed to in the output above i.e., C:/Users/myPC/Anaconda3/python.exe (3.8.3) is the place where Anaconda is installed in my PC, so this seems to be fine.
However, I do not understand what file it is looking for in the last line of the output.

Comment: This looks like a conflict between conda and pipenv. See here on how to make pipenv behave with conda https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50546339/pipenv-with-conda. Note that conda can also create and manage virtual environments, see here https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands

Comment: Thanks for your comment @ApplePie. I get the problem that they are trying to address in the 1st link, i.e., configuring pipenv to use the right python version. I tried the approach mentioned there but still get the same error as captured in my post above. Yes, conda can also create virtual dev environments but within such a virtual dev environment I would like to use pipenv so that I can package and distribute the dependencies in form of a pipfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue myself by referring the solution mentioned in this [github issue](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/10822). Although, this seems to be a workaround for the moment but nevertheless, it works.

I manually copied the python.exe and pythonw.exe from C:/Users/myPC/Anaconda3/ directory into c:\users\myPC\anaconda3\Lib\venv\scripts\nt\